# How to download PDF file into client system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp

I want to download a PDF file from server side into client system. A Report page is changed into PDF file and saved into a project folder that is on server side. Here the problem is that when I access it from client system and try to generate PDF file then I am not sure whether it has successfully generated a PDF file into server side project folder or not and it is not automatically downloaded into the client system. But when I run project from local system then it is working correctly.

Here I post my code, please check it and please give me a solution for this, I need it very much

My code is:

```
protected void btn_print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
                int width = 850;
                int height = 550;
                Thumbnail1 thumbnail = new Thumbnail1(url, 990, 1000, width, height);
                Bitmap image = thumbnail.GenerateThumbnail();
                image.Save(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Dwnld/Thumbnail.bmp");
                imagepath = Server.MapPath("~").ToString() + "\\Dwnld\\" + "Thumbnail.bmp";
                imagepath1 = Server.MapPath("~").ToString() + "\\Dwnld\\" + "Thumbnail.pdf";
                convetToPdf();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }



    string imagepath = null;
        string imagepath1 = null;
        public void convetToPdf()
        {
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            System.Drawing.Size size = PageSizeConverter.ToSize(PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
            PdfPage pdfPage = new PdfPage();
            pdfPage.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
            doc.Pages.Add(pdfPage);
            //  XSize size = PageSizeConverter.ToSize(PdfSharp.PageSize.A4)
            XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
            XImage img = XImage.FromFile(imagepath);
            xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
            doc.Save(imagepath1);
            xgr.Dispose();
            img.Dispose();
            doc.Close();
            Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
            //Get the physical path to the file.
            string FilePath = imagepath1;
            //Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
            Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
            Response.End();
        }
        public class Thumbnail1
        {
            public string Url { get; set; }
            public Bitmap ThumbnailImage { get; set; }
            public int Width { get; set; }
            public int Height { get; set; }
            public int BrowserWidth { get; set; }
            public int BrowserHeight { get; set; }

            public Thumbnail1(string Url, int BrowserWidth, int BrowserHeight, int ThumbnailWidth, int ThumbnailHeight)
            {
                this.Url = Url;
                this.BrowserWidth = BrowserWidth;
                this.BrowserHeight = BrowserHeight;
                this.Height = ThumbnailHeight;
                this.Width = ThumbnailWidth;
            }
            public Bitmap GenerateThumbnail()
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GenerateThumbnailInteral));
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
                return ThumbnailImage;
            }
            private void GenerateThumbnailInteral()
            {
                WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
                webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                webBrowser.Navigate(this.Url);
                webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
                while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                webBrowser.Dispose();
            }
            private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                WebBrowser webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
                webBrowser.ClientSize = new Size(this.BrowserWidth, this.BrowserHeight);
                webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                this.ThumbnailImage = new Bitmap(webBrowser.Bounds.Width, webBrowser.Bounds.Height);
                webBrowser.BringToFront();
                webBrowser.DrawToBitmap(ThumbnailImage, webBrowser.Bounds);
                this.ThumbnailImage = (Bitmap)ThumbnailImage.GetThumbnailImage(Width, Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
        protected void CreateThumbnailImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: See your error log first. Probably you do not have give permissions to the file for write on disk.

Answer (score 2):

One potential problem with this code is that you're writing to the same files for every request. If there are multiple requests at the same time, some of them might fail.

To solve this you could write to the response stream directly, i.e.

```
protected void btn_print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    int width = 850;
    int height = 550;
    Thumbnail1 thumbnail = new Thumbnail1(url, 990, 1000, width, height);
    using (Bitmap image = thumbnail.GenerateThumbnail())
        convertToPdf(image);
}

public void convertToPdf(Image image)
{
    using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument())
    {
        System.Drawing.Size size = PageSizeConverter.ToSize(PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
        PdfPage pdfPage = new PdfPage();
        pdfPage.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        doc.Pages.Add(pdfPage);
        using (XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]))
        {
            using (XImage img = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(image))
            {
                xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    doc.Save(stream, false);
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());
                    stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Response.End();
}
```

**Edit** Modified answer to use `using` statements to release resources.

Comment: when i am trying above code there is error shown i.e.            "Specified method is not supported."  at line "doc.Save(Response.OutputStream);"

Comment: please give me solution for how i can save pdf file to client system from server. when i run project from server computer then it work fine and show pdf file and provide downloading option but when i access it from client machine then it not provide any option for downloading and does not show pdf file.

Comment: Modified code in the answer to use a temporary MemoryStream. Probably Response.OutputStream doesn't support seeking. Please try again.

Comment: Sample code that returns a PDF file to a client can be found here: [PDFsharp.net site](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Clock-sample.ashx). Use `doc.Save(stream, false)` to keep the stream open.

Comment: @PDFsharpTeam Thanks, I overlooked the fact that `PdfDocument.Save(Stream)` closes the stream by default. Edited answer.